# How to import data from excel to textbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, excel

I am working on a project , and i basically have to display data ( cell wise) from an excel file to a textbox. I used the following code

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Partial Public Class Window2
    Dim objexcel As New Excel._ExcelApplication
    Dim objwork As Excel._ExcelSheet
    Dim objworksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Window1.Loaded
        objwork = objexcel.Workbooks.open("D:\jkj.xlsx")
        objworksheet = CType(objwork.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        TextBox1.Text = objwork.cells(1, 1).text
        Textbox2.Text = objwork.cells(2, 1).text
        objexcel.Workbooks.close()
        objexcel.Workbooks.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it is showing the following error

Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Can someone suggest whats wrong with the code? I have searched and read high and low over the net.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes:

1. objwork.cells(1, 1) -> Should be objworksheet.cells(1, 1)
2. objexcel.Workbooks.Quit() -> Should be objexcel.Quit()
3. objworksheet.cells(1, 1).text -> You should split getting the Range object and getting it's text property. It's a general rule of thumb: "Never use 2 dots with COM objects." Not obeying it leads to leaving Excel's thread running even after user closes client app.

You should also consider securing your code with the try-catch block - from my experience there are many unexpected possibilities of getting an exception while working with Office via COM.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void Importarexel(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid tabla)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog myFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

        {
            Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx",
            Title = "Open File",

        };

        if (myFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string ExcelFile = myFileDialog.FileName;
            OleDbConnection conecionexel = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + ExcelFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'");

            try

            {
                string xSheet = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Digite el nombre de la Hoja que desea importar", "Complete");
                if (xSheet.Length > 0)
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" + xSheet + "$]", conecionexel);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    da.Fill(ds, "MyData");
                    tabla.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    tabla.DataContext = "MyData";

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: wpf 2022 import data exel  a datagrid

Comment: using modelo.funciones;
uso de la funcion  
   private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
           Importardatos.Importarexel(datagribuscar);

        }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).